# English sentence as input and translates it into Textese

Tags: vb.net

working on a project where I input a text file and write a sentence in an "English" text box and with a click of a button the program translates it into "textese" type of language. It will only change words listed in the text file and ignore everything else. Below is the code I have, and wondering what is going wrong, it fails to run and highlights my If Then statement, so I think my issue is there but not sure what. A few examples of what is in the text file and how they are ordered / separated by a comma.

anyone,ne1

are,r

ate,8

band,b&

be,b

before,b4

busy,bz

computer,puter

```
Public Class frmTextese

Private Sub btnTranslate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTranslate.Click

    Dim inputData() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Textese.txt")

    Dim english As Integer = 0
    Dim englishSentence As String = txtEnglish.Text

    Dim result() As String = englishSentence.Split(" "c)

    Do While english < (result.Length - 1)
        Dim line As String
        Dim data() As String
        Dim englishArray As String
        Dim texteseArray As String
        For i As Integer = 0 To (inputData.Length - 1)
            line = inputData(i)
            data = line.Split(","c)
            englishArray = line.Split(","c)(0)
            texteseArray = line.Split(","c)(1)

            If result(i).StartsWith(englishArray(i)) Then
                If englishArray(i).Equals(texteseArray(i)) Then
                    result(i) = texteseArray(i)
                End If
            End If
            txtTextese.Text = result(i)
        Next
    Loop

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Does it give you specific error? Do you see a big black dot to the left of your If/Then Statement in the far left part of the screen

Comment: No red errors just a yellow arrow "IndexOutOfRange Exception was unhandled" on the first If statement

Comment: just wanted to  make sure it wasnt your debugger turned on. Ok that means that your array of result(i) or possibly englishArray(i) doesnt have a value in it (its null). See what (i) is and verify you really have an value in that position. You obviously don

Comment: How do I go about changing that? Is it the same idea as result(i) or how does it work? I'm still new to this and trying to learn, I've never split a text file into two arrays and worked with it before. Would I use a nested For Loop using a different letter ?

Comment: Your `For i` loop is based on the length of the `inputData` array, but you are using `i` as the index for other arrays that are not the same size, resulting in trying to access items in an array that don't exist (IndexOutOfRange).  There are a number of issues with your code - e.g. `englishArray` is a string, so `englishArray(i)` is trying to get a single character from that string at position `i`?  Stepping through the code in the debugger may help you find where things aren't working as you expect.

Comment: `englishArray` and `texteseArray` are not arrays, they're merely strings, so you should not index them.  Instead I think you need something like this:  `If result(i).StartsWith(englishArray) Then` and eliminate the next `If` statement since `englishArray` and texteseArray` will never be equal.

Comment: If I start with If result(i).StartsWith(englishArray) Then, is that incorrect? Because it will always start with the englishArray no matter what, how would I change that to checking if the englishArray has the textese replacement word in the text file ?

Answer (score 2):

You only need to compare `result(i)` against `englishArray`.  Also, your `while` loop was an endless loop.  When searching the textese array, once you find a match, you can quit searching and go on to the next english word.  Finally, you should take care to use variable names that describe their purpose.

Look at this code (untested).  I made the string comparison case insensitive, but that is not required.

```
Private Sub btnTranslate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTranslate.Click

    'Get all the textese definitions
    Dim inputData() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Textese.txt")

    Dim english As Integer = 0
    Dim englishSentence As String = txtEnglish.Text

    Dim result() As String = englishSentence.Split(" "c)

    Do While english < (result.Length - 1)
        Dim line As String
        Dim data() As String
        Dim englishArray As String
        Dim texteseArray As String
        For i As Integer = 0 To (inputData.Length - 1)

            'Split the textese entry into two parts
            line = inputData(i)
            data = line.Split(","c)
            englishArray = data(0)
            texteseArray = data(1)

            'Compare the word in the english sentence against the word in the textese array
            'using a case insensitive comparison (not required)
            If result(i).Equals(englishArray, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                'Replace the word in the sentence with its textese version
                result(i) = texteseArray

                'If we found the word, there is no need to continue searching, so 
                'skip to the next word in the english sentence
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        'Increment the loop counter to avoid an endless loop
        english = english + 1
    Loop

    'Take the elements of the result array and join them together, separated by spaces
    txtTextese.Text = String.Join(" ", result)

End Sub
```